# image-rendering: pixelated makes pixels inconsistent sizes even when upscaling by integers

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I let the user pick an image, I convert the resulting `File` object to an `ImageBitmap` using `createImageBitmap()`, I render that `ImageBitmap` onto a `<canvas>` with no scaling applied, then I upscale that canvas using CSS by saying:

```
canvas{
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: scale(2);
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

When I select a .png file containing pixel art where every pixel in the .png is exactly one pixel in the pixel art ([this](https://oops-studio.com/downloads/demospritesheetforso.png) is the image I'm using, for reference), I expect that scaling this .png up by any integer value should create an image where each pixel is consistently square. In this case, going from 1x1 to 2x2.

However for some reason my result looks like this: [image: image depicting issue]

Notice how some pixels are rendered 1x1, others 2x2, and some even appear to be 1x2 or 2x1. Why is this happening?

Snippet to further demonstrate issue:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "https://oops-studio.com/downloads/demospritesheetforso.png";// I'm confortable using a remote image as the source here since I own this domain and can guarantee that the image will not be removed

img.addEventListener("load", () => {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
});
```

```css
body{
  background: black;
}
canvas{
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(2);
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

After some more testing it seems to be an issue with my PC in some way. I tried it in both Opera and Edge (don't have anything else installed) and it was consistently incorrect. I tried it on another machine (in Opera) and it works perfectly.

Any ideas as to why that is?

Comment: The snippet works as expected; I'm seeing an exact x2 image. My guess is you accidentally zoomed in on the website, that replicates the nearest neighbor scaling you describe.

Comment: Nope. I'm certain that I have not accidentally zoomed in on anything, as I've viewed it many different placed in several separate browser tabs and windows. Additionally, I just double checked that my zoom level is set to 100% and it is, and I also viewed it in various other zoom levels and it exhibits the same issues. It only starts working properly once I reach a zoom level of 200%, and every zoom level after that (300%, 400%, 500%) works properly. Anything under 200%, even 100%, do not work properly. The snippet exhibits the same issue as the other application, just to be clear.

Comment: Can't repro here either, latests FF and Chrome on high-res monitor. But Chrome does apply some antialiasing even when not scaling the image, so you may want to try adding `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false` before the `drawImage` to check if it changes something.

Comment: @Kaiido No change from disabling image smoothing. I added a bit more context to my question as well. It seems to be an issue with my PC, as it's consistent across all browsers but fixes itself when running same code on different machine.

Comment: What OS are you on? IIRC Windows has a default 75% zooming set at the OS level.

Comment: Wow... You're correct, thank you! I'm using Windows and my zoom level was set to 125% by default. I changed it to 100% and it works perfectly now. I guess I'll need to get used to everything being so small, lol. If you would like to post this as an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll write up my own for people in the future.

Comment: Windows recommends 125% if the monitor is small but high-res (like a 2K laptop monitor). This affects every app and can screw up GUI layouts. I recommend getting a bigger monitor or using an external monitor so you can remain at 100% OS Zoom without stuff getting hard to read.